# Maxiumn call stack error extjs Array join

Tags: arrays, extjs, extjs5, sencha-architect, extjs6-classic

I am getting Maximum call stack error on this piece of cod can this be re written in any other way.`    prepareHeaderDetailDataForPost: function(headerdata, detailStore) {
        //mark for private
        var me = this,
            detailArray = [];

```
    // hack to set viewmodel formula back into header model.
    headerdata.set('adjustmentNumber', me.getViewModel().get('adjustmentNumber'));
    //headerdata.set('customerRepresentativeNo',this.lookupReference('comboboxcustomerrepnumber').getValue());

    if (!Ext.isEmpty(headerdata)) {
        try {
            headerdata = headerdata.getData({
                serialize: true
            });
            delete headerdata.id;
        } catch (headerError) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Data Error', 'Problem Saving Header Record. <br/>Could not seriralize header record');
            return;
        }
    } else {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Data Error', 'No Header Record present.');
        return;
    }
    delete headerdata.lineItems;
    detailStore.each(function(r) {
        var tmpRecord = r.getData({
            serialize: true
        });
        if (!Ext.isEmpty(tmpRecord.id)) {
            delete tmpRecord.id;
        }
        tmpRecord.additionalCharges.forEach(function(a) {
            delete a.id;
        });
        if (!Ext.isEmpty(tmpRecord.attachments)) {
            delete tmpRecord.attachments;
        }
        delete tmpRecord.totalAmount;
        detailArray.push(tmpRecord);
    });
    return Ext.apply({}, {
        'headerdata': headerdata,
        'detailArray': detailArray
    });
}`
```

Comment: I did not find anything in this code that could cause a maximum call stack size error. Can you make a fiddle that exhibits the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your response Alexander It was my mistake I m calling it twice in another place.